# Is there a differentiable function whose derivative is greater than or equal to 1 everywhere but 0 at 0?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{'}(0)=0$ and $f^{'}(x) \ge 1$ $\forall x \ne 0?$ Prove either way.

I was thinking of coming up with a counterexample such as $x^3$ but adding an expression to make $f' \ge 1$ but that makes $f'(0) \ne 0.$ What would be a rigorous proof otherwise if no such $f$ exists?

Comment: No. Derivatives of differentiable functions satisfy the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A function $f$ such that $f' = 0$ when $x < 0$ and $f' = 1$ when $x \geq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858163/a-function-f-such-that-f-0-when-x-0-and-f-1-when-x-geq-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darboux Theroem  says that the derivative of any differentiable function has IVP. So  no such function exists. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Answer (score 1):

If $x\ne 0$ then by the IMT there exists $y$ strictly between $x$ and $0$ with $\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(y).$

So $\left|\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|\ge 1.$

So $|f'(0)|=\lim_{x\to 0}\left|\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|\ge 1.$